# Is it possible to delete all the session variables except a few?

Tags: php, ajax, jquery

Is it possible to delete all the session variables except a few?

I'm building a website using PHP, MySQL

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$dontDelete = array('test1','test2');
foreach($_SESSION as $key => $value) {
   if (!in_array($key,$dontDelete)) {
      unset($_SESSION[$key]);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 14):

```
$_SESSION = array_intersect_key($_SESSION, array_flip(array('leave', 'all', 'these', 'keys')));
```

Comment: Won't array_keys return array(0,1,2,3) there?

Comment: Looks better. You might want to correct array_intersect_keys to array_intersect_key just to be *totally* correct :)

Comment: @Paul Dixon: Argh. One short line and two faults in there. Thanks for pointing out